# Why does product_tag_edit_form_fields action works in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I am a total newbie to woo-commerce. So please bear with me if I use incorrect terminology or ask something stupid.

I was trying to add a custom field to product tags. I was able to find articles that showed how-to add custom filed to a product category instead (http://www.wpmusketeer.com/add-a-wysiwyg-field-to-woocommerce-product-category-page/).

I modified the actions in the tutorial and replaced `product_cat_edit_form_fields` with `product_tag_edit_form_fields`, `edited_product_cat` with `edited_product_tag` and so on. And it worked well! I was able to add/edit this new field in product tags.

But I can't find this action documented anywhere when I google it out. 
Can anyone tell me why this is working well?

Comment: Hi Jags, I think you need to learn about hooks in wordpress, if you can understand how to use actions and filters, you can do anything with  wordpress/woocommerce, almost all the time you need to find where is the hook that you need directly in the files, and need to understand when to use it, a good starting point could be [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/hooks-wordpress-actions-filters-examples) and if you what to see a full list of hooks and where are they check [this link](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/)

Comment: Thanks for the links Mauro! I will read that right away. And I also found the answer to my question to a certain extent. These actions are like <<taxonomy name>>_edit_form_fields. So I was unknowingly replacing it with another taxonomy.